How can I compile an EXE with GCC such that the .idata and .text sections are merged together?
Given this classic helloworld.c example,
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}

Under normal circumstances, a compiled EXE file consists of several sections, such as .text, .rdata, .idata, and so on.
VC (Visual C++) has a very useful /MERGE: option, which allows all sections to be merged into a single segment in versions prior to VC2010.
However, GCC (MinGW) does not have such a command. Online resources suggest that this can only be achieved through custom linker scripts.
But I've found that merging .text and .rdata sections together is fine, but once .idata is also included in the merge, the program fails to run.
Can anyone help identify the issue? Is it possible that the linker script (LDS) is not written correctly?
OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)
SECTIONS
{
  . = SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  . = ALIGN(__section_alignment__);
  .text  __image_base__ + ( __section_alignment__ < 0x1000 ? . : __section_alignment__ ) :
  {
    *(.text) *(.data) *(.rdata) *(SORT(.rdata$*)) KEEP(*(.pdata*)) *(.bss) *(.idata) *(SORT(.idata$*))
  }
}

Or alternatively, is there a way to achieve this without using an LDS linker script, solely with the GCC MinGW compiler? Excluding manual modification.

Welcome to SE/RE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and you might want to read some of the pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to add new information. -- What does it mean the "the program fails to run"? When you tried to run it under debugger control, where did it fail?

Don't you think that [so] would be a better site to ask this question?

You can't do anything with .idata because the rtld needs to write to it (and your linker script combines everything into one section). That section contains the addreses for your imports (from the data directory entry) resolved by the runtime linker. Some of the other sections like .data will also be written to by your generated code, so you can't combine them into a single .text section (which the rtld will map non-writable).
You can skip over those reqs, if you do the loading yourself (like prior to executing shellcode)... but if you're depending on your platform's loader. Then, no.

@AliRizvi-Santiago How does your first statement match with this answer on StackOverflow?

@Ali Rizvi-Santiago  Thank you for your reply. I don't think it's impossible at all. Visual C++ can merge them into one section, so why can't GCC do the same? Perhaps I'm just not using the correct method.

@the busybee  Initially, I also intended to post my question on the Stack Overflow website, but every time I finished writing the question, it failed to publish. I tried for several days, and it kept prompting me about a robot verification, but the verification link was always inaccessible. It feels very inconvenient that they block normal information in order to prevent spam advertisements.

@thebusybee: I don't have a windows box at the moment to test the /MERGE option with microsoft's linker on more than just .rdata+.text as doc'd. but i'd be very surprised for it to combine its writable .data and executable .text sections together into a single writeable&executable segment and still be compatible with DEP. Have you examined the emitted executable with a PE editor to verify that it's actually putting everything into a single segment (section in pecoff-speak) with wx permissions? Check the data-directory entries too to confirm that the output is not including an import table.

@AliRizvi-Santiago Your first statement references just .idata. Of course one cannot merge .data (and .bss and IDK more) into the same segment as .text.

@wqte45 Well, I'm usually on Linux boxes, so my options are limited. However, on the job I need to use Windows and there is also a GCC. Yet I need to find some time to experiment. -- Strange, your experience with [so]. I do not remember robot verifications, it might depend on your location.

@the-busybee: ??? It mentions _both_. The reason why ".idata" was mentioned first was because that was the segment that was mentioned by the author of the question.

By "statement" I mean the first sentence "You can't do ... section)." I did not mean "comment" or any of the following sentences. Anyway, let's stop this, it leads nowhere.

As per the comments in the question, I took the time to download the Visual Studio Dev Essentials VM in order to prove what had been claimed. I haven't gone towards proving the loader's exact requirements because I figured that it would've been out-of-scope for the original question.
Binutils
As per the question and what was suggested in the comments, we'll use the original ld(1) script and examine the executable it produces.
OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)
SECTIONS
{
  . = SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  . = ALIGN(__section_alignment__);
  .text  __image_base__ + ( __section_alignment__ < 0x1000 ? . : __section_alignment__ ) :
  {
    *(.text) *(.data) *(.rdata) *(SORT(.rdata$*)) KEEP(*(.pdata*)) *(.bss) *(.idata) *(SORT(.idata$*))
  }
}

For this linker script we'll create a file with no dependencies to prove that the linker script is capable of producing "valid" executables.
$ cat >| sample.c
static int for_a_data_section = 0;
int
WinMain(void* hInst, void* hPrev, char* lpCmdLine, int nShow)
{  for_a_data_section++; return 0; }
^D
$ mingw32-make sample.o
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions --param=ssp-buffer-size=4   -c -o sample.o sample.c

Next we'll link the object using the prior linker script which should produce an executable file.
$ i686-w64-mingw32-ld.bfd -T example.ld -o sample.non-working.exe sample.o
i686-w64-mingw32-ld.bfd: sample.exe:/4: section below image base
i686-w64-mingw32-ld.bfd: sample.exe:/16: section below image base
i686-w64-mingw32-ld.bfd: sample.exe:/30: section below image base
i686-w64-mingw32-ld.bfd: sample.exe:/45: section below image base
i686-w64-mingw32-ld.bfd: sample.exe:/57: section below image base
i686-w64-mingw32-ld.bfd: sample.exe:/73: section below image base

# these error messages are a result of not including all the sections

Now we'll look at the sections that will be mapped as segments by the loader. Notice that we only have two sections, .reloc and .text. Both of these are set with the MEM_READ characteristic. The .text section is set with MEM_EXECUTE. (This should've probably been done with a regular PECOFF viewer/editor, but this is what I have available on my current platform.)
$ python -m pecoff -O print -s sample.non-working.exe
<class headers.SectionTableArray> 'Sections' headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[8]
[178] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{0}  Name:.eh_frame       Raw[0x00000400:+0x00000800] Virtual[0xffc00000:+0x0000062c] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[1a0] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{1}  Name:.debug_abbrev   Raw[0x00000c00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0xffc00000:+0x0000013c] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[1c8] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{2}  Name:.debug_aranges  Raw[0x00000e00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0xffc00000:+0x00000020] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[1f0] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{3}  Name:.debug_line     Raw[0x00001000:+0x00000200] Virtual[0xffc00000:+0x00000078] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[218] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{4}  Name:.debug_line_str Raw[0x00001200:+0x00000200] Virtual[0xffc00000:+0x00000090] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[240] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{5}  Name:.eh_frame       Raw[0x00001400:+0x00000200] Virtual[0xffc01000:+0x00000040] Characteristics:(0x40000040,32) :> MEM_READ CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[268] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{6}  Name:.text           Raw[0x00001600:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00001000:+0x0000006c] Characteristics:(0x60000060,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_EXECUTE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA CNT_CODE
[290] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{7}  Name:.reloc          Raw[0x00001800:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00002000:+0x00000010] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA

Running this in Windows 11 Enterprise Evaluation results in either the "This app can't run on your PC" modal popup, or the following:
> .\sample.non-working.exe
Program 'sample.non-working.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application
for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1
+ .\sample.non-working.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\sample.non-working.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Now we'll link the same object without the linker script as a parameter. This will not produce the executable with merged sections that we are demanding, but we are doing this for the sake of having something to compare the previous results to. Running the linker without the -T parameter will result in binutils' ld(1) using the script that it was configured with (ld --verbose).
$ i686-w64-mingw32-ld.bfd -o sample.original.exe sample.o

When we dump the sections from the executable, we can see the .text section has MEM_READ and MEM_EXECUTE set. The .data section and the rest have MEM_READ, or both MEM_WRITE and MEM_READ set.
$ python -m pecoff -O print -s sample.original.exe
<class headers.SectionTableArray> 'Sections' headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[11]
[178] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{0}  Name:.text           Raw[0x00000400:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00001000:+0x00000040] Characteristics:(0x60000020,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_EXECUTE CNT_CODE
[1a0] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{1}  Name:.data           Raw[0x00000600:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00002000:+0x00000004] Characteristics:(0xc0000040,32) :> MEM_WRITE MEM_READ CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[1c8] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{2}  Name:.rdata          Raw[0x00000800:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00003000:+0x00000038] Characteristics:(0x40000040,32) :> MEM_READ CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[1f0] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{3}  Name:.eh_frame       Raw[0x00000a00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00004000:+0x00000040] Characteristics:(0x40000040,32) :> MEM_READ CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[218] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{4}  Name:.idata          Raw[0x00000c00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00005000:+0x00000014] Characteristics:(0xc0000040,32) :> MEM_WRITE MEM_READ CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[240] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{5}  Name:.reloc          Raw[0x00000e00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00006000:+0x00000010] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[268] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{6}  Name:.debug_aranges  Raw[0x00001000:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00007000:+0x00000020] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[290] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{7}  Name:.debug_info     Raw[0x00001200:+0x00000800] Virtual[0x00008000:+0x0000062c] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[2b8] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{8}  Name:.debug_abbrev   Raw[0x00001a00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00009000:+0x0000013c] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[2e0] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{9}  Name:.debug_line     Raw[0x00001c00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x0000a000:+0x00000078] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[308] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{10} Name:.debug_line_str Raw[0x00001e00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x0000b000:+0x00000090] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA

Let's now go back and fix our linker script to ensure the data section being written to by our example is writable. The following example is the same as the one you provided, but it places the two segments that will be written to in the .data segment. We also discard the .debug segments so they're not included in our final executable. It is worth noting that the section names for your object file only have meaning during the linking process. i.e. We only know that the .data section is written to because we implicitly know that our compiler uses this section for writing.
OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)
SECTIONS
{
  . = SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  . = ALIGN(__section_alignment__);

  .text  __image_base__ + ( __section_alignment__ < 0x1000 ? . : __section_alignment__ ) :
  {
    *(.text)
    *(.rdata)
    *(SORT(.rdata$*))
    KEEP(*(.pdata*))
    *(.idata)
    *(SORT(.idata$*))
  }

  .data BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.data) 
    *(.bss) 
  }

  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    *(.debug*)
  }
}

Now we'll link using the new linker script, and then follow up by dumping out the sections in the resulting file. Note that only one of our sections, .data, has MEM_WRITE set. It's worth noting that there seems to be a section that was forgotten in the original linker script, the .reloc section. This is supposed to contain the relocations for the executable, (IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC), and probably needs to be aligned for that reason. However, none of that is relevant since the linker included it anyways.
$ i686-w64-mingw32-ld.bfd -o sample.working.exe sample.o -T working.lds 

$ python -m pecoff -O print -s sample.working.exe
<class headers.SectionTableArray> 'Sections' headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[4]
[178] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{0}  Name:.text     Raw[0x00000400:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00001000:+0x00000068] Characteristics:(0x60000060,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_EXECUTE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA CNT_CODE
[1a0] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{1}  Name:.eh_frame Raw[0x00000600:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00002000:+0x00000040] Characteristics:(0x40000040,32) :> MEM_READ CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[1c8] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{2}  Name:.data     Raw[0x00000800:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00003000:+0x00000004] Characteristics:(0xc0000040,32) :> MEM_WRITE MEM_READ CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[1f0] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{3}  Name:.reloc    Raw[0x00000a00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00004000:+0x00000010] Characteristics:(0x42000040,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_DISCARDABLE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA

Running this executable appears to work without the platform having any complaints.
Microsoft's Linker
As stated in the question, "Under normal circumstances, a compiled EXE file consists of several sections, such as .text, .rdata, .idata, and so on. VC (Visual C++) has a very useful /MERGE: option, which allows all sections to be merged into a single segment in versions prior to VC2010." So, let's explore this.
One caveat, however, is that Microsoft does not appear to have the Visual C++ 2010 Build Tools available publicly. This is amplified due to https://archive.org being down at the moment. The Python wiki, lists https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers, but all of those links appear down. So, this is the version of LINK.EXE that I am forced to use for this answer:
> link nonexist.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.39.33523.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'nonexist.obj'

Checking the help to ensure that it supports the /MERGE parameter.
> link /? | findstr /N "MERGE"
74:      /MERGE:from=to

We will now use the /MERGE parameter to combine the .rdata, .idata, and .data sections into the .text section. We will also include .reloc too...just in case.
> link.exe /merge:.data=.text /merge:.idata=.text /merge:.rdata=.text /merge:/out:sample.mslink.exe sample.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.39.33523.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.data' (C0000040) merged into '.text' (60000020) with different attributes
LINK : fatal error LNK1272: cannot merge '.idata' with any section

It appears to complain about it. So, we have no real choice but to remove it from the parameters and try again.
> link.exe /merge:.data=.text /merge:.rdata=.text /merge:.reloc=.text /out:sample.mslink.exe sample.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.39.33523.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.data' (C0000040) merged into '.text' (60000020) with different attributes
LINK : fatal error LNK1272: cannot merge '.reloc' with any section

It appears to complain about merging the .reloc section as well.  If we remove that section, then we're only left with being able to merge .data and .rdata into the .text section. This unfortunately means that the most recent version of Microsoft's linker appears to guard against merging the .idata and .text sections together.
> link.exe /merge:.data=.text /merge:.rdata=.text /out:sample.mslink.exe sample.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.39.33523.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : warning LNK4254: section '.data' (C0000040) merged into '.text' (60000020) with different attributes

> dir /b sample.mslink.exe
sample.mslink.exe 

Linker scripts
Although the linker script capabilities of ld(1) are very useful, they have no knowledge of what is required by the target platform to run its output. This, of course, is up to the developer writing the linker script.
At the end of an article I'd written, I included a linker script that can be used with MinGW build tools in order to output each of the required segments into one contiguous binary. This is possible because the developer is responsible for performing the load process. The script exports symbols that can be used by the entry point implementation specifically for this purpose.
Although not related to Windows, there's another good example of a linker script at https://secret.club/2023/12/24/riscy-business.html

As requested in comment for reproduceability (with the imports used by the CRT). This is specific to MinGW CRT's requirements and not at all related to the compiler.
$ cat >| t.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}

$ cat working.lds
OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)
SECTIONS
{
  . = SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  . = ALIGN(__section_alignment__);

  .text  __image_base__ + ( __section_alignment__ < 0x1000 ? . : __section_alignment__ ) :
  {
    *(.text)
    *(SORT(.text*))
    *(.rdata)
    *(SORT(.rdata$*))
    KEEP(*(.pdata*))
    *(.eh_frame)
    *(.ctors*)
  }

  .data BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.data) 
    *(.bss) 
    *(.CRT)
    *(SORT(.CRT$*))
  }

  .idata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    // start of imports
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$2))
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$3))
    // sentinel import entry
    LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0);
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$4))
    // import address tables
    __IAT_start__ = .;
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$5))
    __IAT_end__ = .;
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$6))
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$7))
    *(.reloc) 
  }

  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    *(.debug*)
  }
}

$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o t.exe t.c -T working.lds 

$ python -m pecoff -s -Oprint t.exe 
<class headers.SectionTableArray> 'Sections' headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[4]
[178] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{0}  Name:.text  Raw[0x00000400:+0x00002800] Virtual[0x00001000:+0x000027a4] Characteristics:(0x60000060,32) :> MEM_READ MEM_EXECUTE CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA CNT_CODE
[1a0] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{1}  Name:.data  Raw[0x00002c00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00004000:+0x00000114] Characteristics:(0xc0000040,32) :> MEM_WRITE MEM_READ CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[1c8] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{2}  Name:.tls   Raw[0x00002e00:+0x00000200] Virtual[0x00005000:+0x00000004] Characteristics:(0xc0000040,32) :> MEM_WRITE MEM_READ CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
[1f0] headers.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER{3}  Name:.idata Raw[0x00003000:+0x00000800] Virtual[0x00006000:+0x000006d0] Characteristics:(0xc0000040,32) :> MEM_WRITE MEM_READ CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA

$ python -m pecoff -d -Oprint t.exe 
<class datadirectory.DataDirectory> 'DataDirectory' _object_[16]
[f8]         datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT{0}  *0x0:+0x0
[100]         datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT{1}  *0x6000:+0x6d0
[108]       datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE{2}  *0x0:+0x0
[110]      datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION{3}  *0x0:+0x0
[118]       datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY{4}  *0x0:+0x0
[120]      datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC{5}  *0x0:+0x0
[128]          datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DEBUG{6}  *0x0:+0x0
[130]   datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_ARCHITECTURE{7}  *0x0:+0x0
[138]      datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_GLOBALPTR{8}  *0x0:+0x0
[140]            datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_TLS{9}  *0x26ec:+0x18
[148]    datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG{10} *0x0:+0x0
[150]   datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT{11} *0x0:+0x0
[158]            datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT{12} *0x60e4:+0xa8
[160]   datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT{13} *0x0:+0x0
[168] datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR{14} *0x0:+0x0
[170]       datadirectory.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESERVED{15} *0x0:+0x0

On Windows 11 Enterprise using Developer Essentials VM.
PS Z:\shared> ./t.exe
Hello world!


Thank you for your answer and analysis. However, the EXE file linked using the modified LDS script you provided still cannot run. I checked it with a PE analysis tool and found that there is no Import Table, which may be the main reason for the issue.

I'll edit my answer to include the exact input and output files that I'm using, but what platform are you running it on, and what error message are you seeing? I'm building with these packages specifically: mingw32-filesystem-148-3.fc40.noarch mingw32-crt-11.0.1-3.fc40.noarch mingw32-winpthreads-11.0.1-3.fc40.noarch mingw32-headers-11.0.1-3.fc40.noarch mingw32-winpthreads-static-11.0.1-3.fc40.noarch mingw32-binutils-2.41-3.fc40.x86_64 mingw32-cpp-14.1.1-3.fc40.x86_64 mingw32-libgcc-14.1.1-3.fc40.x86_64 mingw32-gcc-14.1.1-3.fc40.x86_64 mingw32-gcc-c++-14.1.1-3.fc40.x86_64.

I used your first LDS linker script, and the generated EXE file indeed only has one section, .text. However, this EXE file fails to run, and analysis software reveals that there is no Import Table found. Perhaps it is included, but the addresses are not correctly resolved.
Using your second LDS script, the compilation is successful and the program can run. But it merely merges other sections into .text, while .idata remains a separate section.

As per my comment on the question, you can't merge .idata into .text. it needs to be writable as per the constraints of the rtld (which dispatches into the crt) that you're using. the original answer uses ld to show that it is not linked with any c-runtime which results in no need for an import table and allowing for all sections to be merged. the answer also shows that link.exe doesn't appear to do what was considered.

@thebusybee, fair enough. edited out the reference. apologies in that case. i originally didn't want to write a proper answer due to not being at home or having access to a windows env, hence my polluting of the comments thinking it could just be briefly explained. but the author's doubt and your poking kind of drove me to proving it. i guess that's a good thing, though, and I'll be more aware next time.

Something else that would also be worth researching would be MinGW's emulated tls or pseudo-relocations (pseudo-reloc.c) which are used in MinGW's CRT (mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt) and might affect the rtld's initializers for TLS. Such as it likely being that they'll need to be aligned to the size of a pointer. clang/lld apparently uses native tls, and only gcc is presently missing it (this is all according to the author of github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw in his HN comments anyways). I haven't gone down these avenues, tho, since it being clang-only would make it a non-solution to this question.
